# How to handle childAdded the same as observeSingleEvent

Tags: swift, dictionary, snapshot

I have a UITableView which will load correctly with this function:

```
    channelRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.updateTableViewWithPlayers(snapshot: snapshot)
    })

func updateTableViewWithPlayers(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot)
    {
print(snapshot)
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://omega-towers-f5beb.appspot.com")
            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                for each in snapDict{
                    print(each.value)
                    let UIDs = each.value["userID"] as? String
                    let pictureVersion = each.value["PictureVersion"] as? String
                    if let allUIDS = UIDs{
                        if let allPictureVersions = pictureVersion{
```

Which prints this as an output if there is 1 user in it:

```
Snap (-KeEan584BeCQ0eJ2dxs) {
    "-KeEb2XMrCUFLfO90y0v" =     {
        PictureVersion = 6;
        userID = N4GifT8HvfRrDEkC09ARC1DnYyI3;
        username = pietje;
    };
    name = sdddd;
}
{
    PictureVersion = 6;
    userID = N4GifT8HvfRrDEkC09ARC1DnYyI3;
    username = pietje;
}
```

This works good. Now I want to update the tableview when a new user joins in. I added this function:

```
    channelRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        self.updateTableViewWithPlayers(snapshot: snapshot)
    })
```

This prints out:

```
Snap (-KeEbYVJIle8dhP1Oyxm) {
    PictureVersion = 6;
    userID = N4GifT8HvfRrDEkC09ARC1DnYyI3;
    username = pietje;
}
6
pietje
N4GifT8HvfRrDEkC09ARC1DnYyI3
```

I do not know why this output is different. I want to have 1 function that can handle both functions (observe and observeSingleEvent) but I am not sure why the observe function does not work correctly. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say it prints out seems weird but the idea is the following: **observeSingleEvent** will run only once as the name suggest. **observe** on the other hand will be invoked every time that type needs to be invoked by Firebase Cloud. Meaning if you use ** observeSingleEvent** for type **.childAdded**, your block will only be invoked for one child where normally **.childAdded** runs for every child in that snapshot. And will continue to be invoked every time a new child is added. If you want a to update your tableView every time a new child is added, you should be using **observe** and **.childAdded**.

I'm not sure if I answered your question or not. If not, do let me know.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is why the above function does not work for childAdded, but works well for observeSingleEvent. Thank you.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. I deleted the whole observeSingleEvent and used childAdded since it loops through all existing childs.

Comment: Great! Yeah thats what I meant.

Comment: OK brah :D/////